# Im working with a document config.env and it is not making work after of be called on index doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, dotenv

For some reason the next code into config.env is not working, I'm using nodes libraries and I have dotenv library but the code is having an error with the tokens

```
CLIENT_URL = https://localhost:3000
JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION = 6f19abs00317c8e6f63f7661181313eb551f7a7b4c34c6ssssssssssssssssssssssssss0641f57e94ccabdd8d5be2fe07dfda21651473e0a39
JWT_SECRET = 764366csssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss9871e390c6d1214db7af574c0afc82d292aa96217aa647a88d3cc8accd4
JWT_RESET_PASSWORD = 1sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss074dd9871e390c6d121asdqwdqwdqwdqwdqwdqwdf47a88d3cc8accd4
EMAIL_FROM = rsaas@gro.com
MAIL_KEY = SG.wwewewrrrrr9PXodfPNF3aALV1C10hI
```

The terminal is bringing me it

C:\xampp\htdocs\seth\api\src\config\config.env:1
CLIENT_URL = https://localhost:3000
^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\seth\api\src\index.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

But I don't know why, I'm calling this document for a Rest API, and the method for being called is it:

```
const config = ("./config/config.env");

// Config dotev
require('dotenv').config({
    path: require(config)
})
```

All looks fine so I don't exactly know where's the problem

Comment: @matt
The alternative for dotenv was my first option but the problem is that the console brings me it: "API key does not start with "SG.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node can't `require` plain files. Any files that use `require` to load need to be parsed by Node, so can be Javascript or JSON.

To use your existing code, the config file should be JSON (or js)

```
{
"CLIENT_URL": "https://localhost:3000",
"JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION": "xxx"
}
```

Alternatively [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) can load that config

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './config/config.env' })
```

I'm not sure about the spaces, it might need values like:

```
CLIENT_URL=https://localhost:3000
JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION=xxx
```

Comment: The alternative for dotenv was my first option but the problem is that the console brings me it: "API key does not start with "SG.".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is logic, after of research about the theme, I found different solutions, but not all of them work, so I'm tried for a console.log and I found that the env variables are not being declared.

With that information, I deducted that the routing path is not working, and after of time I found the next code __dirname.

It is for get absolute routes, so I applied it:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/config.env'})
```

now it works with that simple change

And the reason for that the console is bringing me the API key does not start with SG. is because I'm calling it in another document, so the console doesn't lie, the API key was undefined